# In case of poco when we create SecureServerSocket what happens id port is already in use?

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

`SecureServerSocket(some port);`
what happens if port is not available ?
I cant find any document about the same

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, a **NetException "Address already in use"** will be thrown.

This is not unique to `SecureServerSocket` but to all Poco sockets.

It will be generated due to the error that occurs in the low level OS socket `bind` function.

The **ERRNO** will be set to **EADDRINUSE**, Poco will detect that and throw the NetException.

I don't specifically see the NetExceptions that Socket can throw at construction time (or any time) in the documentation though.

See [SocketImpl.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/3fc3e5f5b8462f7666952b43381383a79b8b5d92/Net/src/SocketImpl.cpp#L1261).